# Google Compute Engine: /syslinux/vmlinuz.A has invalid signature

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Since last week, my Google Compute Engine instances do not boot because of this error.

```
[0m[37m[40m[0m[30m[40m[2J[01;01H[0m[37m[40m  Booting `verified image A'



error: /syslinux/vmlinuz.A has invalid signature.



Press any key to continue...



  Failed to boot both default and fallback entries.
```

[image: Google Cloud Console showing the serial port 1 output of failed VM]

Does anybody know the cause of this failure?

Comment: Filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149154224

Comment: It makes sense to switch to the GRUB shell and check the boot image availability, size and modification date. Have you made any significant changes right before?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. In GCP console, "Enable connecting to serial ports" is grayed out, and thus I cannot check GRUB.

Comment: On the web page "VM instance details" you should click "Edit" atop, next tick the checkbox "Enable connecting to serial ports", and then click "Save". The remote access option "Connect to serial console" will become available.

Comment: @mebius99 Thanks. The option is now available. But the opened console did not accept my keyboard input.

As per  issuetracker.google.com/issues/149154224, it seems there's "Secure Boot" option.

Comment: Have you tried to stop the VM and disable Secure Boot?

Comment: Yes, problem persisted with secure boot opion off.

Comment: When the kernel file is unavailable, the bootloader prints another error : `error: file '/boot/vmlinuz-...' not found. `.  As shown on the screenshot, in your case the bootloader is in place, it is actually lanuched, and it **can access** the kernel file. That means that there is no issues with the disk numbers, boot order, partition table, partition labels & UUIDs, EFI boot directories and files. The issue is rather caused by the wrong kernel signature: it is unknown to the EFI shim.

Comment: @mebius99 Thank you for comment. I stopped digging this issue. As per issuetracker.google.com/issues/149154224 , it's not caused by Google Compute Engine and only happened to my instance. I'll create a new boot disk.